# Cloned Select Fields Not Working - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/V8bwZ/5/

Hi Guys,

I am having a lot of trouble getting my cloned select fields to work properly. All cloned select fields are failing to reflect the selected item that they are populated with. Also, when trying to select a new option on a cloned select field, the selected option does not update.

I have a feeling that there is a very simple solution that I have been overlooking. Thank you for your help.

```
<div class="address">
    <div class="address-clone section-clone">
        <!-- Contact Details Box -->
        <ul class="section-header list-divider blank" data-inset="false" data-role="listview" data-corners="false" data-icon="false">
            <li data-icon="plus" data-theme="f"><a class="clone-section">Address <span class="count"></span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <fieldset class="half">
            <div class="wrap closer">
                <input type="text" class="address_name" name="address_name" placeholder="Address Name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap closer">
                <select name="address_type" class="address_type">
                    <option value="home">Home</option>
                    <option value="work">Work</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="full">
            <div class="wrap"><input type="text" class="address_street_1" name="address_street_1" placeholder="Street"/></div>
            <div class="wrap"><input type="text" class="address_street_2" name="address_street_2" placeholder="Street 2"/></div>
            <div class="wrap"><input type="text" class="address_city" name="address_city" placeholder="City"/></div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="half">
            <div class="wrap closer">
                <select name="address_state" class="address_state">
                    <option value="blank">State</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="wrap closer">
                <input type="text" class="address_zip" name="address_zip" placeholder="Zip Code" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>  
</div>
```

-- Javascript

```
<script>
var section = $('.address');
var sectionClone = $('.address').clone().addClass('cloned');

$(section).append(sectionClone);

$('.address-clone').each(function(i, t){
    $(this).find('.count').html(i + 1);
});

var addrClones = $('#contact-edit .address').children('.address-clone');

contact.address.forEach(function(n){

    var i = contact.address.indexOf(n);

    $(addrClones[i]).find('.address_name').val(n.address_name);
    $(addrClones[i]).find('.address_street_1').val(n.address_street_1);
    $(addrClones[i]).find('.address_street_2').val(n.address_street_2);


    if(n.address_type == 'work'){
        $(addrClones[i]).find('.address_type option[value="work"]').attr('selected',true);        
    }

    $(addrClones[i]).find('.address_city').val(n.address_city);
    $(addrClones[i]).find('.address_state').val(n.address_state);
    $(addrClones[i]).find('.address_zip').val(n.address_zip);

});



// clone address section
$('.clone-section').click(function(){

    alert('test');

    var section = $(this).closest('.address');
    var sectionClone = $(this).closest('.address').html();

    $(section).append(sectionClone);



    $('.address-clone').each(function(i, t){
        $(this).find('.count').html(i + 1);
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're cloning an element with `id`. Which duplicates the `id` making your `HTML` invalid. Use classes instead for dynamic templates....

Comment: Good observation. I removed the id and replaced it with a class of address. Still no luck. I updated the code on this page and the jsFiddle as well.

Comment: Possible duplicates:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617624/jquery-mobile-cloned-form-elements-not-working
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950234/why-a-select-in-a-cloned-div-has-a-wrong-behavior-when-refreshed
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570257/issue-in-select-option-in-jquery-mobile
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474400/jquery-dynamic-added-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because JQueryMobile is binding javascript actions to display the values on change.  BUT, when you clone them, you are losing those events.
BUT, i tried just quickly reinitalizing them with ".selectmenu()" and found that causes a problem too because you are cloning them after JQueryMobile has modified them, and reinitalizing them screwes up the UI a bit.

--edit--
looks like cloning enhanced widgets isn't supported.
you could use jquery to strip away the enhancements and then call .selectmenu() on the cloned selects to reinitalize them.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4735

Comment: Thanks Chris, you've helped me gain an insight on how JQM handles it's elements. I also found this page that details some of the limitations of the earlier versions of JQM regarding this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617624/jquery-mobile-cloned-form-elements-not-working

Comment: I was able to make this script work storing my cloned elements(html) in pagebeforecreate then binding them to my output on pageinit. From there I called trigger('create') on the cloned elements and all is well.